# Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Given the following schema:

```
create table account_type_a (
  id SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
  some_column VARCHAR
);

create table account_type_b (
  id SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
  some_other_column VARCHAR
);

create view account_type_a view AS select * from account_type_a;
create view account_type_b view AS select * from account_type_b;
```

I try to create a *generic* trigger function in plpgsql, which enables updating the view:

```
create trigger trUpdate instead of UPDATE on account_view_type_a
for each row execute procedure updateAccount();    
create trigger trUpdate instead of UPDATE on account_view_type_a
for each row execute procedure updateAccount();
```

An unsuccessful effort of mine was:

```
create function updateAccount() returns trigger as $$
declare
  target_table varchar := substring(TG_TABLE_NAME from '(.+)_view');
  cols varchar;
begin
  execute 'select string_agg(column_name,$1) from information_schema.columns
           where table_name = $2' using ',', target_table into cols;
  execute 'update ' || target_table || ' set (' || cols || ') =  select ($1).*
           where id = ($1).id' using NEW;
  return NULL;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The problem is the `update` statement. I am unable to come up with a syntax that would work here. I have successfully implemented this in PL/Perl, but would be interested in a plpgsql-only solution.
Any ideas?

**Update**

As @Erwin Brandstetter suggested, here is the code for my PL/Perl solution. I incoporated some of his suggestions.

```
create function f_tr_up() returns trigger as $$
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  my $target_table = quote_ident($_TD->{'table_name'}) =~ s/^([\w]+)_view$/$1/r;
  my $NEW = $_TD->{'new'};
  my $cols = join(',', map { quote_ident($_) } keys $NEW);
  my $vals = join(',', map { quote_literal($_) } values $NEW);
  my $query = sprintf(
    "update %s set (%s) = (%s) where id = %d",
    $target_table,
    $cols,
    $vals,
    $NEW->{'id'});
  spi_exec_query($query);
return;
$$ language plperl;
```

Comment: Could you post your (complete) PL/Perl solution as another answer so we can compare. That would be great! +1 Interesting question, btw!

Comment: Thanks for posting the PL/Perl version. Nice opportunity to compare the two languages for the same job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While [@Gary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343288/939860) is technically correct, it fails to mention that PostgreSQL **does** support this form:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET (col1, col2, ...) = (expression1, expression2, ..)
```

Read [the manual on `UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

It's still tricky to get this done with dynamic SQL. I'll assume a simple case where views consist of the same columns as their underlying tables.

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_view AS SELECT * FROM tbl;
```

#### Problems

The special record `NEW` is not visible inside [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). I pass `NEW` as a single parameter with the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE`.

As discussed, `UPDATE` with list-form needs individual *values*. I use a subselect to split the record into individual columns:

```
UPDATE ...
FROM  (SELECT ($1).*) x
```

(Parenthesis around `$1` are not optional.) This allows me to simply use two column lists built with `string_agg()` from the catalog table: one with and one without table qualification.

It's not possible to assign a row value as a whole to individual columns. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

> According to the standard, the source value for a parenthesized
> sub-list of target column names can be any row-valued expression
> yielding the correct number of columns. PostgreSQL only allows the
> source value to be a row constructor or a sub-`SELECT`.

`INSERT` is implemented simpler. If the structure of view and table are identical we can omit the column definition list. (Can be improved, see below.)

#### Solution

I made a couple of updates to your approach to make it shine.

Trigger function for `UPDATE`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_trg_up()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl  regclass := quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA) || '.'
                  || quote_ident(substring(TG_TABLE_NAME from '(.+)_view$'));
   _cols text;
   _vals text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _cols, _vals
          string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ')
        , string_agg('x.' || quote_ident(attname), ', ')
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
   AND    NOT attisdropped   -- no dropped (dead) columns
   AND    attnum > 0;        -- no system columns

   EXECUTE format('
   UPDATE %s
   SET   (%s) = (%s)
   FROM  (SELECT ($1).*) x', _tbl, _cols, _vals)
   USING NEW;

   RETURN NEW; -- Don't return NULL unless you knwo what you're doing
END
$func$;
```

Trigger function for `INSERT`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_trg_ins()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl regclass := quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA) || '.'
                 || quote_ident(substring(TG_TABLE_NAME FROM '(.+)_view$'));
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s SELECT ($1).*', _tbl)
   USING NEW;

   RETURN NEW;  -- Don't return NULL unless you know what you're doing
END
$func$;
```

Triggers:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_instead_up
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON a_view
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION f_trg_up();

CREATE TRIGGER trg_instead_ins
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON a_view
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION f_trg_ins();
```

Before Postgres 11 the syntax (oddly) was [`EXECUTE PROCEDURE` instead of `EXECUTE FUNCTION`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307500/3684) - which also still works.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=78fe0833131ae46fb9223a7a42979854)* - demonstrating `INSERT` and `UPDATE`
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a3a6/1)</sub>

#### Major points

- Include the schema name to make the table reference unambiguous. There can be multiple table of the same name in one database with multiple schemas!
- Query `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` instead of `information_schema.columns`. Less portable, but much faster and allows to use the table-OID.

  - [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- **Table names are NOT safe against [SQLi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)** when concatenated as strings for dynamic SQL. Escape with [`quote_ident()` or `format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) or with an [object-identifer type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html). This includes the [special trigger function variables `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TG_TABLE_NAME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)!
- Cast to the [object identifier type `regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) to assert the table name is valid and get the OID for the catalog look-up.
- Optionally use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to build the dynamic query string safely.
- No need for dynamic SQL for the first query on the catalog tables. Faster, simpler.
- Use `RETURN NEW` instead of `RETURN NULL` in these trigger functions unless you know what you are doing. (`NULL` would cancel the `INSERT` for the current row.)
- This simple version assumes that every table (and view) has a unique column named `id`. A more sophisticated version might use the primary key dynamically.
- The function for `UPDATE` allows the columns of view and table to be in *any order*, as long as the set is the same.
  The function for `INSERT` expects the columns of view and table to be in *identical order*. If you want to allow arbitrary order, add a column definition list to the `INSERT` command, just like with `UPDATE`.
- Updated version also covers changes to the `id` column by using `OLD` additionally.

Comment: Thank you for this profound answer! I have some catching up todo incorporating your points into my code...

Comment: Nice solution. Although I don't really understand why you need the `FROM  (SELECT ($1).*) x` in the update. Wouldn't a `where id = ..` be just as good?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well, the `FROM (SELECT ($1).*) x` is needed, so I can refer to individual values in the list used in the `SET` clause easily. I guess I could write `($1).col` instead of `x.col`, too. But I thought that was less elegant and probably slower than breaking up the record once. You also reminded me, that the `WHERE` clause was missing.

Comment: Hmm. But you are not using the values from the select. The values for the UPDATE statement are taken from the `vals` variable which is populated from the select on `pg_attribute`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `vals` is just another column list, table-qualified with `x.`. Results in `SET (id, txt, day) = (x.id, x.txt, x.day)`. And `x` is the alias of the subquery.

Comment: @sschober: Added another improvement to cover updates on the `id` column as well.

Comment: if `NEW` is a record why would not smth like `execute 'update t set (FULL_LIST) = $1 WHERE..' using NEW` work?.. don't we have neater record to row "cast" then listing all columns and `from alias`?.. or smth like `execute 'update t set (FULL_LIST) = (($1).*) WHERE..' using NEW`...

Comment: @Vao: `UPDATE` demands a list of individual columns. I added a quote from the manual above.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql doesn't support updating multiple columns using the `set (col1,col2) = select val1,val2` syntax.

To achieve the same in postgresql you'd use

```
update target_table
set col1 = d.val1,
    col2 = d.val2
from source_table d
where d.id = target_table.id
```

This is going to make the dynamic query a bit more complex to build as you'll need to iterate the column name list you're using into individual fields.  I'd suggest you use `array_agg` instead of `string_agg` as an array is easier to process than splitting the string again.

[Postgresql UPDATE syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)

[documentation on array_agg function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: While you are technically correct, there is still a way. But that's only a lesser hurdle here. I added an answer.

Comment: @Erwin good catch.  I've got to admit, I've never used that syntax.