# limit trigger scope using modifiable views

Tags: postgresql, triggers, view

We have an architecture where modifications to data tables trigger the creation of jobs and subsequent processing by handlers (written in perl and notified via channels). During job handling the need arises in the handlers to update the data tables. To avoid recursion we:

1. need to disable the triggers before the update
2. do the update and
3. enable triggers again.

As new handlers might be added later on in the project lifetime, disabling and enabling the triggers might be forgotten, so this might become a maintainance problem.

As an alternative approach, we devised the idea to limit the scope of the triggers to front-end-specific views. These views are made writeable by `instead of` triggers (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql)). Handlers update the data tables directly during job execution, thus not triggering any recursive jobs. We have a working implementation of this approach.

In my opinion, we trade complexity here: algorithmic (enable disable triggers) for structural (additional views). We currently tend to chose the latter, but I wanted some input from you guys on the matter... Is this a sound approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using different users. Triggers only run if user <> 'handler'. You can set custom functions to run as "security definer" which means the user that created them. You can add a condition to trigger definitions (WHEN) that can check the current user.

Then check out [pgtap](http://pgtap.org/) which will let you check you've not missed anything.

Comment: That's an interesting idea I'll explore. Thanks for the hint!