# How to create a synonym for a user in PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am migrating this Oracle command to PostgreSQL:

```sql
create view DBA_ha as select * from DBA_USER where username!='ha';
create synonym ha.DBA_USER for DBA_ha;
```

Please suggest to me how I can migrate the SYNONYM command above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Alias for PostgreSQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300003/create-alias-for-postgresql-table)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not need synonyms, because it has the more flexible `search_path`.

To solve your particular problem, create the view in the schema `ha`. Anything else would be needlessly complicated.