# psql: display functions with \df that do *not* contain a certain pattern

Tags: regex, postgresql, psql, postgresql-extensions

Because I installed dblink extension into the (default) public schema, `\df` will display all the dblink related functions. I only want to view customized function.

How can I see function that not contain text "dblink"?
So far what I tried.

```
\df !~ *dblink*
\df !~ *dblink*
\df ! *dblink*
\df !*dblink*
\df ! *'dblink'
\df !~* 'dblink'
\df !~ 'dblink'
\df !~ dblink
```

`\df dblink*` will get all the function begin with "dblink". I just want the opposite.

regex link:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP
psql link:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS

Comment: That's one of the reasons I install extensions into a separate schema.

Comment: You cannot get that with `\df`, you'll have to write a metadata query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Advanced users can use regular-expression notations such as character classes, for example [0-9] to match any digit. All regular expression special characters work as specified in Section 9.7.3, except for . which is taken as a separator as mentioned above, * which is translated to the regular-expression notation .*, ? which is translated to ., and $ which is matched literally.

Seems there is no specific mention of we cannot do that.

Comment: not is an operators. I guess this is the issue.

Comment: Your problem is that `~`, `!~` etc. are operators. You won't easily find a regular expression that matches everything that does *not* contain a certain string.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Not that easily, but I think I found an bearable workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What you asked

> How can I see function that not contain text "dblink",

[Regular expressions are supported in these patterns.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS) *Without* adding an operator like `!~*`.
**Unfortunately**, some special characters are excluded. A regexp with a [negative lookahead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE) would solve your request nicely. But no luck, because that happens to involve the `?` characters and, quoting [the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS)

> All regular expression special characters work as specified in [Section 9.7.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), except for [...], `?` which is translated to `.` [...]

Barring that, I can only think of character classes to *exclude* patterns as a workaround:

```
test=> \df public.([^d]|.[^b]|..[^l]|...[^i]|....[^n]|.....[^k])*
```

Displays all tables in the schema `public` that do not start with 'dblink'. It's a regular expression with *branches*:

- The 1st branch `[^d]` allows all names that do not start with 'd',
- The 2nd branch `.[^b]` allows all without 'b' as 2nd character

Etc.

Since the long string is awkward to type, you can save it to a psql variable, and interpolate that:

```
test=> \set dbx 'public.([^d]|.[^b]|..[^l]|...[^i]|....[^n]|.....[^k])*'
test=> \df :dbx
```

You can even put that `\set` command into your `~/.psqlrc` file to have it loaded in psql automatically.

#### SQL solution

Alternatively, you can query the system catalogs:

```sql
SELECT n.nspname AS "Schema", p.proname AS "Name"
     , pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) AS "Result data type"
     , pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS "Argument data types"
     , CASE p.prokind WHEN 'a' THEN 'agg' WHEN 'w' THEN 'window' WHEN 'p' THEN 'proc' ELSE 'func' END AS "Type"
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc p
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  pg_function_is_visible (p.oid)  -- only visible functions like plain \df
AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'      -- exclude catalog schemas
AND    p.proname NOT LIKE 'dblink%'    -- exclude pattern
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 4;
```

While this is a lot more versatile, it is also more complicated. And may change for future versions ...

#### Simpler: separate schema for extensions

That said, the clean solution is to avoid the mess and **install extensions into a separate schema**, like [a_horse already hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256034/psql-df-display-function-not-contain-certain-string-pattern?noredirect=1#comment124193504_70256034). This related answer has detailed instructions:

- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107418/3684)

If you go that route, and use a schema named `extensions`, you can then simply *change* the schema where `dblink` is installed with:

```
ALTER EXTENSION dblink SET SCHEMA extensions;
```