# How to derive column name in UPDATE from variable in a PL/pgSQL trigger function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a simple trigger function in PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
 BEGIN 
 IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
 UPDATE relation 
 SET child_name = new.name 
 WHERE table_reference_1 = new.id; 
 END IF; 
 RETURN NULL; 
 END;
```

Is it possible to replace `table_reference_1` (which is column name) with variable? I want to do something like:

```
 BEGIN 
 IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
 UPDATE relation 
 SET child_name = new.name 
 WHERE TG_TABLE_NAME = new.id; 
 END IF; 
 RETURN NULL; 
 END;
```

`WHERE TG_TABLE_NAME = new.id` is supposed to mean:
*"`new.id` is equal to the value of the column, whose name is equal to the parent table's name"*.

Comment: How can a table name equal an id? But in general you need to use dynamic SQL if you want to use identifiers that are stored in a variable: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+dynamic+sql

Comment: > How can a table name equal an id?<  

It's not what i'm trying to do. Check the description - i've added a bit more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain SQL does not accept variables for identifiers. I see two options for your trigger function:

### 1. `CASE` expression

For a couple of known alternatives (and an optional catch-all).

```
UPDATE relation r
SET    child_name = NEW.name 
WHERE  CASE TG_TABLE_NAME  -- "switched case"
        WHEN    'possible_column1'          -- value!
          THEN r.possible_column1 = NEW.id  -- identifier!
        WHEN    'possible_column2'
          THEN r.possible_column2 = NEW.id
        --  etc.
        -- ELSE r.default_column = NEW.id
        -- or no ELSE ...
       END;
```

No `ELSE` means the expression evaluates to NULL if no option matches. And only `TRUE` qualifies in a `WHERE` clause.

### 2. Dynamic SQL

For any number of alternatives or for alternatives unknown at the time of coding.

```
EXECUTE format('
   UPDATE relation
   SET    child_name = $1
   WHERE  %I = $2'
 , TG_TABLE_NAME  -- being used as column name
USING NEW.name, NEW.id;
```

#### Notes

- If the column name doesn't actually exist, this raises an **exception**. Your transaction is rolled back [unless you trap it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).
- PL/pgSQL operates with prepared statements. The query plan for option 1 *can* be reused within the same session if Postgres finds that re-planning does not generate better plans than a generic plan. Option 2 is planned *every time*. This may be irrelevant / a disadvantage / an actual advantage, depending on your use case ...

  - [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)
- Always make sure that dynamic SQL is safe against SQL injection (by maliciously crafted table names in this case). I defend against it with [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) using `%I`.

Related answers with more explanation:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql/15351196#15351196)
- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)